# Device back button handling - android development

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to implement app lock kind of feature in android, for this purpose i am starting a new intent before any activity gets started! e.g after user clicks on camera, my app will open a password screen on it, but the problem is when i click "**back**" from device, that window goes out and application gets opened.(which should not be happened at any cost) what i have to do?

Comment: The back button can be disabled by overriding the onBackPressed method of your Activity

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood your question correctly, but maybe you want to remove activity from back stack... check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14112219/android-remove-activity-from-back-stack

Comment: You can handle the back button pressed method in your activity or password dialog class.:)