# How can I remove my activity from the backstack when I click on the back button

Tags: android, android-intent

I want my activity to be clear form the back stack when user press back button. I am using this intent to open my activity:

```
Intent i = new Intent(context, OutGoingActivity.class);
i.putExtra("Number", incomingNumber);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
context.startActivity(i);
```

I want my OutGoingActivity Activity will be removed from the stack when I press the back button.

Every time when ever I launch my activity, a new activity should be opened instead of from the stack.

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14112219/android-remove-activity-from-back-stack

Comment: finish() will do the trick

Answer (score 5):

Just use **finish();** for remove current activity.

Like

```
Intent i = new Intent(context, OutGoingActivity.class);
i.putExtra("Number", incomingNumber);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
context.startActivity(i);
// use finish()
finish();
```

When you call **finish()** method, **onDestroy()** method will be execute.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to remove your activity from stack then you can use below code :

```
    android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
    System.exit(1);

     Intent mintent = new Intent(context, OutGoingActivity.class);
     mintent .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
     context.startActivity(mintent);
     finish();
```

But if you want to remove all the activities then you should try below code :

```
ActivityCompat.finishAffinity(OutGoingActivity.this);
finish();
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Thanks for your replay. No it is not working, i am launching my OutGoingActivity from a broadcast receiver class the triggers on every incoming call. Now the problem is, first time it launch my activity over answering screen and when i click on end button my activity move to the stack and when i got the incoming call second time, my activity launch from the stack and this time answering screen come on the top of my activity. I want to my activity will always be visible on top of the answering screen.

Comment: @TarunBhutani :  please see my edit.

Comment: @TarunBhutani then do one thing, if you want to remove activity on end button click, then call `finish()` on end button.

Comment: I have used finish() as well as the above, but none of them have solved my problem. I can still see my task in the task bar.