# How to remove activity from back stack in android?

Tags: android

I have 4 activity let suppose activity "A","B","C" and "D" when I move from C>D>A and when I press Device back button from Activity "A",then "C" became visible to me instead of exist from app.How can I acheive this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android remove Activity from back stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14112219/android-remove-activity-from-back-stack)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Activity A you can finish all activities in onResume for that you need to store all activity's this in staic variable

Activity B

```
public static B b;
oncreate(){
//...
b=this;
}
```

Do the same for C and D and in A

```
onResume(){
   clearAllTasks();
}

public void clearAllTasks(){
 if(B.b!=null){
   B.b.finish();
 }
 if(C.c!=null){
   C.c.finish();
 }
 if(D.d!=null){
   D.d.finish();
 }
}
```

in manifest

```
<application>
  <activity android:name="A"
     android:noHistory="true">
  </activity>
  //...
</application>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can destroy your activity when you call the next activity. So after `Intent` you can call `finish()` method to destroy that activity.

Check this one

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NextActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

When you use this it does not go to previous activity instead it finishes the activity.

**OR**
You can also use `NO_HISTORY` flag

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
```

Answer (score 1):

Override your backpress like this, from where you want to go back to home screen

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setCancelable(true);
        builder.setTitle("Exit");
        builder.setMessage("Do you want to exit?");
        builder.setInverseBackgroundForced(true);
        builder.setNegativeButton("Yes",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    /*finish();
                    System.exit(0);*/
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
        builder.setPositiveButton("No",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
        builder.create();
        builder.show();


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are trying to exit from your app. 
Here is your answer: 
[How to exit from the application and show the home screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3226495/how-to-exit-from-the-application-and-show-the-home-screen)

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Working for me:

```
   restart.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY |
                                Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK |
                        Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                startActivity(restart);
```