# Remove an activity from back stack from another activity?

Tags: java, android

I have a main activity `A` from where I can launch a second activity `B`.
It's possible to remove `B`from back stack using a method in `A`?

Comment: try this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39010977/how-to-remove-activity-from-back-stack-in-android

Comment: @Wuagliono     public void onBackPressed() {
        Toast.makeText( MainActivity.this, "Can NOT Go Back", Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be hacks that would allow such a thing like making `B` not part of the back stack, but this also means that when you switch away from your app to another and return to it that the user should land on `A` again, not `B`.

It would be better to know what exactly you want to achieve as there might be an "official" to do just that. If you, for example, just want that in a chain of `A -> B -> A` you don't want to navigate back to `B` after being in the last `A` state, the answer would be to start `A` always with the intent flag `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK`, as it would throw away all the history and would start `A` anew.