# Saving the Activity - Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-activity, onsaveinstancestate

I have an android application with two activities - `activity_login.xml` and `activity_dashboard.xml`.

When the users open the app for the first time, it should take them to the `activity_login` and then, they should log in and go to `activity_dashboard` which has a **Logout** button.

If they press on the **Logout** button, it should again go back to the `activity_login`. If they press the back button, it should exit the app. And when they press the app icon, it should take them directly to `activity_dashboard`.

I am confused about how to save the activity and go back to that particular activity when the app icon is pressed.

Comment: This might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50573272/6383029

Comment: @Mustansir That is not the kind of answer I am looking for. His question is about saving activities when the user is still in the app. Mine is about saving the activity after the user exits the app.

Comment: That's why people often add a "splash" screen that decides which one to go to

Comment: @AnikethChavare what are you looking save exactly in Activity?

Answer (score 0):

If you are logged in, you have to call finish() after you launch intent to go to activity_dsahboard.In that case, if you are still logged in, you will directly go to activity_dashboard.Here is a sample,

```
          Intent I = new Intent(this,ActivtyDashBoard.class);
           startActivity(i);
           finsih();//place it after you launch intent to go to 
                    //activity_dashboard
```

If you wanna store the login status, use shared preference to save an identifier whose value will be set on successful authentication..Just create some logic and save an identifier in shared perefrence.This way is not ideal for professiona apps.You need a whole lot od complex mechanism to do so.

Comment: And, where exactly should I add the `finish();` in my code?

Comment: read my answer once again.. you only have to call finush if you are logged in :updating sample code

Comment: please mark my answer as accepted and upvote it if it helps.. comment if you have a doubt

Comment: Actually, It is not working. If I clear the activity in the phone and open my app, it is not going to the dashboard activity.

Comment: put your logic right.. if you are checking correctly if you are logged in and then you are using the code on that condition, no way its not going to work..maybe in your login activity ,you are not correctly checking if you are logged in..double check your code

Comment: i am 100 percent sure you are making the mistakes , i pointed out in my last comment..paste the code in chat, i will debug

Answer (score 0):

Its simple you need to use SharedPreference to store login status defualt values will if false when use login change value to true, every time you open app simply check status and navigate accordingly, when user click back button check in onResume method that user is login or not then open that activity

Use this
https://medium.com/viithiisys/android-manage-user-session-using-shared-preferences-1187cb9c5cd8

Answer (score 0):

## Observe Dashboard Termination.

Start Dashboard Activity with startActivityForResult() and observe how Dashboard Activity was finished.

1. If the Dashboard Activity was closed by pressing the Logout button it will not do anything.
2. if it was closed by pressing the back button it will finish LoginActiivty too.

**Here is the full code:**

> LoginActivity

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button login;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       login = findViewById(R.id.login);

       login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View view) {
               Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, DashBoard.class);
               startActivityForResult(intent, 9000);
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int req, int res, Intent result) {
         super.onActivityResult(req, res, result);
         if(res== Activity.RESULT_CANCELED){
            finish();
         }
     }
 }
```

> DashBoard code

```
public class DashBoard extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button logout;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savecInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savecInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.dash_board);
        logout = findViewById(R.id.logout);
        logout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
               setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK);
               finish();
            }
         });
    }
}
```